# Unable to fetch a set of objects when using criteriabuilder and entitymanager

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-entitymanager

When i'm trying to use the CriteriaBuilder and entityManager to fetch a set of attributes from an entity called SeedRecord, i get the following error:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate
>   appropriate constructor on class
>   [DTOs.EntityDTOs.AffiliateLinksPerSeedSummaryDTO]. Expected arguments
>   are: long, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, POJOs.AffiliateLink
>   [select new
>   DTOs.EntityDTOs.AffiliateLinksPerSeedSummaryDTO(generatedAlias0.id,
>   generatedAlias0.varietyName, generatedAlias0.produceName,
>   generatedAlias1) from POJOs.SeedRecord as generatedAlias0 inner join
>   generatedAlias0.affiliateLinks as generatedAlias1]

According to the stacktrace my AffiliateLinksPerSeedSummaryDTO wrapper class should have a constructor that includes a field of which the type is `Pojo.AffiliateLink`. The actual field however is a reference to a set of Affiliatelinks, not a single Affiliatelink row so this doesn't make any sense. Can anyone tell me what could be causing this? Here is the code of the wrapper class:

```
public class AffiliateLinksPerSeedSummaryDTO {
    private long id;
    private String varietyName;
    private String produceName;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<AffiliateLink> affiliateLinks;
    private long specificCount;
    private long generalCount;

    public AffiliateLinksPerSeedSummaryDTO(long id, String varietyName, String produceName, Set<AffiliateLink> affiliateLinks) {
        this.id = id;
        this.varietyName = varietyName;
        this.produceName = produceName;
        this.affiliateLinks = affiliateLinks;
    }
```

All the field names are exactly the same to the SeedRecord field names.

Heres the code snippet i use to fetch the desired fields/objects.

```
    EntityManager em = seedRecordDao.getEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<AffiliateLinksPerSeedSummaryDTO> criteria = builder.createQuery(AffiliateLinksPerSeedSummaryDTO.class);
    Root<SeedRecord> seedRecordRoot = criteria.from(SeedRecord.class);
    criteria.select(
            builder.construct(
                    AffiliateLinksPerSeedSummaryDTO.class,
                    seedRecordRoot.get("id"),
                    seedRecordRoot.get("varietyName"),
                    seedRecordRoot.get("produceName"),
                    seedRecordRoot.join("affiliateLinks")));

    List<AffiliateLinksPerSeedSummaryDTO> affiliateLinksPerSeed = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

EDIT: My latest attempt to get things working was by retrieving tuples instead of using a wrapper object. The problem now is that the resultlist is zero despite there being values in the database. This is what i've made now:

```
    public Set<AffiliateLinksPerSeedSummaryDTO> getAffiliateLinksPerSeed(){
        EntityManager em = seedRecordDao.getEntityManager();
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        Metamodel m = em.getMetamodel();
        EntityType<SeedRecord> SeedRecord_ = m.entity(SeedRecord.class);
        CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteria = builder.createTupleQuery();
        Root<SeedRecord> seedRecordRoot = criteria.from(SeedRecord.class);
        Path<Long> idPath = seedRecordRoot.get( "id" );
        Path<String> varietyNamePath = seedRecordRoot.get("varietyName");
        Path<String> produceNamePath = seedRecordRoot.get("produceName");
        Join<SeedRecord,AffiliateLink> affiliateLinks = seedRecordRoot.join("affiliateLinks");
        criteria.multiselect(idPath,varietyNamePath,produceNamePath);

//        criteria.select(
//                builder.construct(
//                        AffiliateLinksPerSeedSummaryDTO.class,
//                        seedRecordRoot.get("id"),
//                        seedRecordRoot.get("varietyName"),
//                        seedRecordRoot.get("produceName"),
//                        seedRecordRoot.get(SeedRecord_.getSet("affiliateLinks",AffiliateLink.class))));

        List<Tuple> affiliateLinksPerSeed = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
        log.info("the count is: " + affiliateLinksPerSeed.size());
                //seedRecordDao.getAffiliateLinksPerSeed();
        return affiliateLinksPerSeed.stream().map(tuple ->{
            Map<Boolean, Long> collect = ((List<AffiliateLink>)tuple.get(affiliateLinks)).stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(AffiliateLink::isGeneral, Collectors.counting()));
            return new AffiliateLinksPerSeedSummaryDTO(((Long)tuple.get(idPath)), ((String)tuple.get(varietyNamePath)), ((String)tuple.get(produceNamePath)),collect.get(true), collect.get(false));
        }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
```

Comment: `fetch` maybe ??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
seedRecordRoot.joinSet("affiliateLinks")
```

Comment: i would love to try your suggestion but i have another problem, could you check out my edit please?